# Mockito. How to mock a static method with args for integration tests

Tags: java, mockito, integration-testing

I use mockito-core 5.4.0 and try to mock a static method with arguments, but it doesn't work.

```
public record TestObject(
   String test
) {}

public class MyClass {
   public static String staticMethod(TestObject obj) {
     // do some logic
   }
}

======================================
var mock = Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)
mock.when(() -> MyClass.staticMethod(any()).thenReturn("")
```

And I'd want to return from mocked static method value of TestObject::test.
e.g. somewhere in deep of my code:

```
var testObj = new TestObject("someTest");
var res = MyClass.staticMethod(testObj);
sout(res) // here I'd want to see: someTest
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `thenAnswer` to acomplish it:

```
    try (MockedStatic<MyClass> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)) {
        mock.when(() -> MyClass.staticMethod(Mockito.any(TestObject.class))).thenAnswer(
                (Answer<String>) invocation -> {
                    TestObject arg = invocation.getArgument(0);
                    return arg.test();
                }
        );

        var testObj = new TestObject("someTest");
        var res = MyClass.staticMethod(testObj);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

its documented here: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs

Comment: `Object[] args = invocation.getArguments(); TestObject arg = (TestObject)args[0];` is a very verbose way to write `TestObject arg = invocation.getArgument(0);`

Comment: And the main my purpose was that to need to mock static methods for integration tests, but Mockito doesn't mock across different threads.